# OpenGL: How to make text appear at the same pixels regardless of camera orientation?

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, jogl

I have text that I am successfully rendering in OpenGL:

```
    GLUT glut = new GLUT();
    gl.glRasterPos2d(10, 10);
    glut.glutBitmapString(GLUT.BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, "We're going to the moon!");
```

I would like this text to appear in the same location on the user's screen (occupying the same pixels) regardless of camera orientation. How should I go about doing this?

(I'm using JOGL.)

Comment: I commented on my answer to your previous question. I think the trick is to use `glWindowPos` instead. `glRasterPos` causes the passed-in point to be transformed using the current modelview and projection matrices.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I wasn't sure if SO etiquette demanded I make a new question or not.

Comment: Also, your answer is correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I don't know Java, warning):

```
glPushMatrix() //save the camera state
glLoadIdentity()
//draw your text here
glPopMatrix() //restore the camera state
```

This resets the camera location to the origin for any rendering commands following the `glLoadIdentity()` call.